# Reverse concurrent misfunction

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to implement a function that inserts a numeric element in it's corresponding place in a list, however I have a problem with parenthesis

> (not (= (1 3 5 6 7 9 16) (((1 3) 5) 6 7 9 16)))

I suspect is because the reverse is executing in a strange way, since if I execute

> (my-flatten '(((1 3) 5) 6 7 9 16))

I get the real answer:

> (1 3 5 6 7 9 16)

Here's my code:

```
(defn insert [x lst]
    (loop [prev () lst lst]
        (cond
        (empty? lst) (my-flatten (cons (reverse prev) (list x)))
        (> (first lst) x) (my-flatten (cons (cons (reverse prev) (list x)) lst))
        :else (recur (conj prev (first lst)) (rest lst)))))
```

Comment: Would you consider editing your original question and show an example of your list before inserting a number and what you want it to look like after? I see essentially a tree-like structure in the beginning starting with (not (= ... but am a little puzzled as to what you are trying to do. Also, will these numbers always be in order, or could your function be presented with numbers out of order? To ask a different way is `(((1 3) 5) 6 7 9 16)` the start or finish and could this sequence ever have the numbers out of order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you do not have a "problem with parentheses" but a problem with lists.

Instead of using first `cons` and then flattening, you should just use `concat`.  You can also combine the two base cases then.

On the efficiency side, you should not append single elements to the end of a singly-linked list in a loop, because that would result in quadratic runtime.  Instead, append to the front and reverse when done.

```
(if (or (empty? lst) (> (first lst) x))
    (concat (reverse prev) (list x) lst)
    (recur (cons (first lst) prev) (rest lst)))
```

Exercise for the reader: what are the pre- and postconditions, and what are the loop invariants?